# How can I optimise this SQL query

Tags: sql

This query does the job, but I am sure it can be improved. Any tips would be much appreciated :)

```
SELECT RIH.ItemName, RI.FieldAnswer, RIH.IsConditional
FROM ReportItemHeader AS RIH
  INNER JOIN ReportItem AS RI
    ON RIH.ItemID = RI.ItemID 
      AND RIH.ReportID = RI.ReportID 
WHERE RIH.ReportID = 2080258 
  AND RIH.SectionNumber = 3

EXCEPT 

SELECT RIH.ItemName, RI.FieldAnswer, RIH.IsConditional
FROM ReportItemHeader AS RIH
  INNER JOIN ReportItem AS RI
    ON RIH.ItemID = RI.ItemID 
      AND RIH.ReportID = RI.ReportID 
WHERE RIH.ReportID = 2080258 
   AND RIH.SectionNumber = 3 
   AND RIH.IsConditional = 1 
   AND RI.FieldAnswer = ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the second `SELECT` if you adapt the first `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT     RIH.ItemName, RI.FieldAnswer, RIH.IsConditional
FROM       ReportItemHeader AS RIH
INNER JOIN ReportItem AS RI
        ON RIH.ItemID = RI.ItemID AND RIH.ReportID = RI.ReportID 
WHERE      RIH.ReportID = 2080258 AND RIH.SectionNumber = 3 
       AND NOT(RIH.IsConditional = 1 AND RI.FieldAnswer = '')
```